# Passing value from PHP to JS win Ajax body

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm passing some value from my Controller to a Javascript file using Ajax success function. Then, I'm using the value to draw some charts.

My controller :

```
 $result =array(
     "PourcentageCommande" => $PourcentageCommandee,
     "nombreCommandePassee" =>$Commande,
     "NonFinance" =>$NonFinance,
     "PourcentageNonFinance" =>$PourcentageNonFinance
);
echo json_encode($result);
```

My JavaSscript :

```
success: function(result) {
    console.log(PourcentageCommande);
    $("#CommandePasses").data('easyPieChart').update(result.PourcentageCommande);
    $('span', $("#CommandePasses")).text(result.PourcentageCommande);
},
```

But instead of getting one value **(20 in the exemple)** while using PoucentageCommande, I'm getting this:

```
{
    "PourcentageCommande":20,
    "nombreCommandePassee":2,
    "NonFinance":0,
    "PourcentageNonFinance":0
}
```

Comment: `console.log(PourcentageCommande);` is not `console.log(result .PourcentageCommande);`

Comment: I'm using **result.PourcentageCommande** to create a pie chart but it shows me the same text

Comment: console.log(result);

Comment: I shows the same thing, I just need to use the value separately

Comment: This looks odd - "PourcentageCommande" => $PourcentageCommandee, the double ee ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try parsing your AJAX response within JSON.parse() function in this way

```
 success: function(result) {
     var data = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(data );
    $("#CommandePasses").data('easyPieChart').update(data.PourcentageCommande);
    $('span', $("#CommandePasses")).text(data.PourcentageCommande);
},
```

Comment: Still giving the same result

Comment: try to add  header('Content-Type: application/json'); before
echo json_encode($data);

Comment: It doesn't work and I don't know why :/ I tried this :`json_encode(array($num1, $num2));`  `var result = $.parseJSON(output);` `result[0]` But it didn't work also

Comment: have you try with eval() instead  of $.parseJSON ? like so: var result = eval(output). Don't forget to cast all numeic values before pass them to charts. use parseInt() and parseFloor()

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using jQuery, you can use jQuery `getJSON()` function to get preliminary parsed JSON data on GET request.

```
$.getJSON('url-to-you-ajax-file.php', {
    some_data: someData,  // Some data passed to the server,
    some_data: someData,  // which you can retrieve as $_GET['some_data'] variables
    some_data: someData
}).done(function(result) {
    $("#CommandePasses").data('easyPieChart').update(result.PourcentageCommande);
    $('span', $("#CommandePasses")).text(result.PourcentageCommande);
});
```